# Need to create a lamda function on AWS that trigger CPU alert every 1 minute and send SNS notification if alarm is above threshold i mean in alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns, metrics

Can anyone please help me

I want to write a lamda function which checks every 1 minute the CPU utlization of an linux ec2 instance and is the utilization is above the threshold value means if the alarm is "in-alarm" state till than keep sending the notification through SNS via email , once it s below threshold so SNS notification should stop

Currently in AWS if an alram is breached above threshold , it will send SNS but for one time

SO want a lamda function that will keep triggering SNS notification , till the alarm is below thresold.

Would appreciate if someone can please help me in writing this Lamda function

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a Lambda. In CloudWatch you can create an Alarm linked to the CPU utilization metric of your EC2 instance. In the Alarm setting there are two parameters that can help you:

1. **Period**: how often you want the metric to be checked by the CloudWatch agent
2. **Datapoint to alarm**: "`the number of datapoints within the evaluation period that must be breaching to cause the alarm to go to ALARM state.`".

If you set the Period reasonably short and Datapoint to `1`, you will get notifications continuously until the CPU utilization metric does not go below the threshold that you set.

Comment: Thanks Alessandro tried what you said above , i am still not able to get the SNS notificaton...Suppose if an alarm has breached CPU Utliization than we will get a SNS but suppose utilization remains above 70 percent for an hour , we will get the SNS notification because as per AWS offical docs , the alarm needs to go back to OK state than only a new SNS will be triggered , thats why i need to write a lamda function in order to achieve this